What does "Trouble initializing Branch. Task exceeded timeout." from Branch.io mean?
I have a react-native app (Expo) that uses Branch.io's RN SDK for deep links and deferred deep links.
On Android only, the branch.subscribe() method is passing through this error on app start up:
Trouble initializing Branch. Task exceeded timeout.

What does it mean and how can I prevent the error? I've not been able to find any Branch.io documentation about this error.
I'm having trouble with deferred deep links on Android and I'm wondering if this error might be related, even though it comes from a different part of the code.

Update
This error is inconsistent.
The day after posting this SO question, I tried the deep links again, on two different Android devices. This time, there were no errors and the deep links worked on both devices, even the deferred deep links.
Then, two days after that, I tried again. There was an error on the Pixel device and the link didn't work, but no problem on the Samsung device. Then, after restarting the Pixel device, the deep links worked without error.

Linking configuration for react-navigation:
const config = {
  screens: {
    'reset-password': 'reset-password',
    registration: 'registration',
    'not-found': '*',
  },
};

const linking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
  config,
  getInitialURL: async () => {
    const recentParams = await branch.getLatestReferringParams();

    if (
      recentParams['+clicked_branch_link'] &&
      recentParams['$deeplink_path']
    ) {
      return prependSchema(recentParams['$deeplink_path'] as string);
    }

    const installParams = await branch.getFirstReferringParams();

    if (
      installParams['+clicked_branch_link'] &&
      installParams['+is_first_session']
    ) {

      const clickTimestamp = installParams['+click_timestamp'];

      if (clickTimestamp) {
        const tenMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 10;
        const now = Date.now();
        const clickTimestampMillis = clickTimestamp * 1000;

        if (now - clickTimestampMillis < tenMinutes) {
          if (installParams['$deeplink_path']) {
            return prependSchema(installParams['$deeplink_path'] as string);
          }
        } else {
       
        }
      }
    }
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    return url;
  },
  subscribe(listener) {

    const linkingSub = Linking.addEventListener('url', (event) => {
      if (isBranchUrl(event.url)) return;
      listener(event.url);
    });


    const unsubscribeBranch = branch.subscribe(({ error, params, uri }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error);
        return;
      }


      if (!params || !uri) return;
      

      if (params['+non_branch_link'] || !isBranchUrl(uri)) return;

      if (!params['+clicked_branch_link']) return;

      if (params['$deeplink_path']) {
        listener(prependSchema(params['$deeplink_path'] as string));
      } else {
        
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribeBranch();
      linkingSub.remove();
    };
  },
};


Branch SDk is not directly supported by RN Expo.
Refer the below thread,
Link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/78508991/25100904

Thank you for your reply. The answer you linked to says that @config-plugins/react-native-branch is required when using with Expo, and that's exactly what I'm using. The Expo documentation also says that react-native-branch should be used for deferred deep links.
Furthermore, it works on iOS and, if you read the updated post, it works intermittently on Android.
So "incompatible with Expo" is not the answer.
